# How do I cast a function with a derived argument to a function with a base argument?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class named `Reciever` that has a function called `recieve(const Event *)`, where `Event` inherits from `BaseEvent`. I want to create a bind to a specific instance of that class. The instance is called `rec`. To do this I use:

```
void(Reciever::*func)(const Event *) = &Reciever::recieve;
auto recievePtr = std::bind(func, &rec, std::placeholders::_1);
```

However, when I try to store this in a vector, I have to specify an `std::function` that takes a `BaseEvent` as the input, not an `Event`, like so:

```
std::vector<std::function<void(const BaseEvent*)>>
```

How can I cast `recievePtr` so I can store it properly in the vector? Is this even possible? The issue with using a function pointer to a `BaseEvent` is that the `Reciever` can have multiple `recieve()` methods with different derived classes all based on `BaseEvent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something along the following. This compiled and ran fine on my machine. Visual Studio targeting platform toolset v120.

```
Reciever rec;

std::vector<std::function<void(const BaseEvent*)>> vector;

vector.push_back(
    [&rec](const BaseEvent* event)
{
    rec.recieve(static_cast<const Event*>(event));
});

vector.push_back(
    [&rec](const BaseEvent* event)
{
    rec.recieve(static_cast<const EventD*>(event));
});

const BaseEvent* e = new Event();
const BaseEvent* d = new EventD();

vector[0](e);
vector[1](d);
```

Comment: Hmm, this removes the overhead of bind. I wonder if there's a better way though.